# How to loop over csv files without importing the csv module?

Tags: python

I want to extract data from a csv file that is already open. For each line, I want to extract data (which is separated by commas) at columns 4, 15, and 16. How can I do this without importing any new modules?

Comment: Homework Problem?

Comment: Why don't you want to import any modules?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split(",")
        # do stuff with columns[3], columns[14], columns[15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open the file-like object, with (could be done with a context manager), something like this:

If you have a CSV file like this

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
```

you could catch the line in python with the `readline` function, and use the string function `split()`, so you get a list, of sub strings that would be each of your columns.

```py
filename = 'file.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    row = f.readline().split(',')
    print(row)
# output -> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

you could also do the same but iterating over the file like

```py
filename = 'file.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        print(row)
# output -> ["1", "2", "3"]
#           ["1", "2", "4"]
```

This would be an easy way to not use the CSV module.